# Prevent direct access to a file, allow google doc viewer

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, permissions

I have a folder with pdf files and I want to prevent direct access but allow google doc viewer to display the file.

I tried .htaccess, changing linux permissions and nothing worked fine (Direct access is forbidden but I get this when viewing with doc viewer: Sorry, we are unable to retrieve the document for viewing or you don't have permission to view the document)

Anyone done this before? Thanks!

Comment: what is google doc viewer? a google app?

Comment: docs.google.com/viewer it enables you to embed files by passing in the url

Comment: don't you understand that this site is using the same "direct access" to download your file?

Comment: And don't you understand that he is asking whever it is possoble to make the file accessible only to certain ip or domain?

Comment: @abruski nope, I dont'. judging by his attempt to solve the problem with **file** permissions, he doesn't seem to be able to tell one from another

Answer (score 0):

You should create your folder, before deploying the application check this folder's permissions, and then try again. This will work if your url is right! If it does not work, please ask again and give more details about your application.